# use sprite kit for an utility app?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, utility

I'm planing on making an utility app that could help people create table plans for sitting guests. 
The thing is, the only way I see this is by letting users create first their own room, with the correct number of tables and sits, then populate the room with the guest list.

But to do that, I was thinking on using the Sprite Kit technology, because it seems to be an quick and easy way to make 2D schemes, use sprites and rely on coordinates.

**Here comes the questions :**

- Is it possible to make an utility app with a "game" core ? Would Apple allow me to do so ?
- If Sprite Kit is not an option, and regarding the fact I'm actually working on xcode 6 + Swift, what would be the alternative to make this process of letting the user create a room that uses X,Y coordinates?

I hope I'm clear, if you have any questions, I'll be happy to complete my requests. Thanks folks !

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the design of your application and what it's requirements in terms of user interface. With SpriteKit, many of the interface elements provided by UIKit are not available and you'd have to build your own if you wanted to use SpriteKit exclusively.

However, there is nothing stopping you from also using UIKit for certain elements such as a UITableView, but it would be a separate view and input would need to be handled via UIKit system. With SpriteKit you don't have a bunch of UI elements to work with.

SpriteKit would mainly be most useful if you need animation and game-like functionality in your utility app.

Apple wouldn't restrict you from using SpriteKit for any kind of app.

In terms of an x,y coordinates, any element you create via SpriteKit or otherwise is going to allow you to position it in that way.

From SpriteKit programming guide, first sentence actually:

"Sprite Kit provides a graphics rendering and animation infrastructure that you can use to animate arbitrary textured images, or sprites."

That is what makes it ideal for games, however not limited to that.

Comment: Thanks ! I think I'll need something with the best of the both worlds, a tableview or a grid with raws and columns and the flexibility of Spritkit to move freely items in the view. I'll do some more researches, thanks again :)